# cordova whitelist doesn't work in android

Tags: cordova

For cordova 5.0.0, I have set:

```
<access origin="*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

and used

```
<script src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

in my html, but when I have launched it, the log says that:

```
url blocked by whitelist
```

Anyone had this problem earlier?

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html "On Android 2.3 and before, domain whitelisting only works for href hyperlinks, not referenced resources such as images and scripts. Take steps to avoid scripts from being injected into the application."

Comment: I have also experienced this issue... I just verified that without changing any of my code, this works on 4.3.0, so I believe this is either a bug on the latest version of Cordova or something has changed in how to whitelist for Android that I don't see in the documentation yet (it works fine for me on iOS on 5.0.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by using the following plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist and then adding an appropriate Content Security Policy in addition to the normal access origin policy in the config.xml.

Below is a summary of the steps to do this:

- Using the CLI, add the whitelist plugin: `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist`
- Likely this is already in place, but in config.xml add an access origin to whitelist your domain, such as: `<access origin="https://*.MYDOMAIN.com" />`
- Add a [Content Security Policy](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#content-security-policy) to  in necessary HTML files, such as index.html: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://*.MYDOMAIN.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`
- Build and run the android project from the CLI again: `cordova run android`

Note that it may be helpful to look at the logcat to see what errors if any you ae receiving. This can be accomplished from the command line with: `adb logcat`

Also, as noted in my comment above, this appears to be an issue with 5.0.0. None of these steps are required with 4.3.0, so it may be easier to just use that version if possible.

Also, note that if you are copying and pasting from above, I am using https, so if you just need http make sure to remove the 's' :)

Comment: hey , i use the cordova android platform cli to create one android project and it unexpectedly add the cordova-plugin-whitelist? I used to think that it will add this plugin automatically. Thanks for your answer,

Comment: No problem... I hope your project is going well.

Answer (score 0):

It is a troublesome problem, I do all the config and it doesn't work, so i
modify its source code:

the request is handled by:

```
PluginManager.shouldAllowRequest
```

I change the last "return false" to "return true" and all work well

Comment: This is a dangerous way to bypass the whitelisting functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you config.xml is located right next to your index.html, otherwise it wont be found.